# Android Studio connection issue

Tags: android, kotlin

Am having a problem in connecting my huawei Y7 2018 phone with android studio,each time i try connecting it via the usb option it still doesnt appear on  my android studio even after allowing the usb debugging option on and the weird part of it, it connects to other phones.Kindly help to solve this problem.

Comment: My list for checking with this is the following: Is debugging allowed? Is the wired connection something else then charge mode? On windows you need sometimes a driver to connect to the device - so can you access the device via OS? Is ADB printing out any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for ADB drivers are properly installed n are compatible with your device. Connect your phone to pc n open terminal n-type `adb devices` check whether your device shows up or not, if not you have to install your device compatible drivers(optional try universal ADB drivers or google ADB drivers).